# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, exception

I am getting the above error when I upload my app to the hosting company.(asp.net)
DB is a local sql mdf in app_data directory.
on local asp.net dev server everything is ok.
I am using LINQ to SQL Classes, is there anything that can be related to that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most probably need to tweak your connection string to match your hosting environment.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the feature of attaching mdf files from the App_Data directory is a feature that is exclusive to SQL Server Express edition. Most likely your hosting company is using another edition of SQL server that does not support this.